# Using CSS3 calc for background positioning without modernizr

Tags: css, safari

I have specific need to style a single div with background image that references to the right and not the left, as it is the default background-position.

I used:

```
div {
 background-position: calc(100% - 100px) center;
 background-position: -webkit-calc(100% - 100px) center;
 background-position: -moz-calc(100% - 100px) center;
}
```

The problem is with older Safari versions ( and probably with other older browsers).

Rather going to use modernizr, I thought to use the following:

```
div {
 background-position: center;
 background-position: calc(100% - 100px) center;
}
```

So, old browsers that will not understand the calc, will still position the bg image to the center, while newer browsers will use the second background-position property, as it will override the first one.

This seems to give a kind of simple solution...
What are your thoughts against this (obviously not so elegant) approach ?

Answer (score 0):

You can fake it with a transparent border:

```
background   : url('/yourimg.png') no-repeat right center;
border-right : 100px solid transparent;
```

Comment: not bad idea, but this also moves all the div to left, and will probably require additional styling and positioning for any other elements on the page that will be affected by the div's new position and size.